# GCP PubSub Subscriber stopAsync().awaitTerminated() hangs

Tags: java, asynchronous, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I am calling `subscriber.stopAsync().awaitTerminated()` and it never returns. When I pause the debugging I see that a bunch of threads "grpc-default-worker-something" appear to be stuck on `private native int kevent0(int var1, long var2, int var4, long var5);` call. Main thread is waiting on `java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park()` on `UNSAFE.park(false, 0L)` call

Before I try to stop the subscriber it behaves as expected (initialization, `startAsync().awaitRunning()` call, `MessageReceived` callbacks)

Has anyone had a similar issue or has any ideas how to tackle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you have messages that have not been acked or nacked.
The client keeps a count of outstanding messages and hangs waiting for it to reach `0`, which it never will if you have codepaths that do neither.

Comment: This indeed was the case. I was sure that this would not be an issue after ackDeadline has passed for all messages. Do you know if there is a way of getting outstanding messages list from the PubSub API?

Comment: Deadlines are extended up to one-hour by default. So take that in to account. Also some fixes around improving those timeouts have dropped quite recently with more coming - so very version specific whether it would work after timeout or not. There is no list API available